# How to make login in codeigniter restserver

Tags: codeigniter, rest, authentication, codeigniter-restserver

I'm using [Codeigniter rest-server library](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver).

I'm having some doubts about authentication of this library.

```
//In config file    
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234'];
```

I want know how to make login with the user of are in  my table in database and keep this logged user in a session.

PS: Sorry about my english and sorry if something is wrong

From Brazil

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) instead sessions to authenticate users. Besides being quite safe, you will be following the pattern of not saving state in a RESTful API.